# Change EditText to TextView on focus change

Tags: java, android, layout, textview, android-edittext

I have an EditText view where the user inputs a number and another EditText directly next to it. When the user clicks the second EditText I would like to change the first EditText to a TextView. How can I go about this?

Comment: Would be easier just making the first ET to not-editable, i.e. diabled. To do what you pretend... you should remove the ET from the layout and create new object... disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `FrameLayout` containing first `EditText`and `TextView`(hidden). Then you add `onClickListener` for the second `EditText` and there you set first `EditText` hidden and show `TextView`. Remember to set the text of first `EditText` into `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Edittext1.setFocusable(false) on edittext2 on focus

Answer (score 1):

Inside the listener function for editing finished for `EditTextview`, get the coordinates of the `EditTextView`, create a `TextView`, assign the value of `EditTextView` to `TextView`, remove the `EditTextView` and add the `TextView` to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both in your layout in the same spot. Make one invisible. Toggle visibility as needed.

In your case, it will be changing visibility from EditText to Textview when editText2 is focused.